# Can a MonoTouch Dialog have no sections?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I'm trying to use MTD to make a table that's just a flat list of elements, but it looks like you can't add Elements to the RootElement; you have to have a child SectionElement and add Elements to it.  But this makes a Section header in the table that MTD creates, **even if the table view style is `UITableViewStyle.Plain`**, and I don't want that header.

Is is possible to avoid having that header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no header visible if you use `new Section ()`, otherwise you might have something else set in your `DialogViewController`.

Comment: Okay, that works, thanks!  It's not very obvious that if you want no section you have to add a section anyway.  They should make a note of that in the docs, I think.